# remove site url from links Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to display link into my website like this :

```
$url = 'google.com';
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Check it !</a>
```

What I don't understand now is that, the output href is not `google.com` but `mydomain.com/google.com`.

I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append **http://** before your url

Try below code:

```
 $url = 'http://www.google.com';
   <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Check it !</a>
```

Comment: Great to help keep helping :)

Answer (score 3):

Please use this code for site url .

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
   <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Check it !</a>
```

If you don't add http then it will open your domain name and then your $url variable name so please add http in your url.